# Is this dangerous? Unchecked cast: Any? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Quest> Android Studio compose firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

Should I try t fix, or can I just leave it like this. (yellow squiggly)

'''

```
when (val questsResponse = viewModel.questsState.value) {
            is Response.Loading -> ProgressBar()
            is Response.Success<*> -> LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding)
            ) {

                items(items = questsResponse.data as ArrayList<Quest>) { quest:Quest ->
                    QuestListItem(//yellow squiggly occurs in above "as" cast
                        quest

                    )
                }
            }
```

'''

val questsResponse: Response<List<Quest>>

public final val data: T

Response wrapping made me do this as cast elsewhere.

```
sealed class Response<out T> {
object Loading: Response<Nothing>()

data class Success<out T>(
    val data: T
): Response<T>()

data class Error(
    val message: String
): Response<Nothing>()}
```

or maybe typecheck in lazyscope, but that seems clumsy

Comment: So it's a warning, right?

Comment: It's ok if you're sure that the data stored in those particular fields is always going to be the same type as you are casting the result to be. If you refactor your database structure, it will also require refactoring so plan your structured well in advance. Then, the warning can be `@Suppress`ed.